# PyGPU Information/Documentation

Tags: python, cuda, opencl, gpu

I'm trying to quickly learn how to write some programs for GPUs using the PyGPU library I found. Initially, I thought this was going to be a very easy task, but I couldn't find any documentation or tutorials for this. I do not have any knowledge of C or any of the current frameworks provided by NVIDIA or ATI, so can anyone suggest a good jumping-off point?

Comment: Writing programs for the GPU isn't easy. Just dive in the material and keep trying until it makes sense. There is no easy way, sorry.

Comment: You would probably like ArrayFire's Python interface.  It is well-documented, here:  http://www.accelereyes.com/afpy.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PyGPU doesn't appear to have been updated since 2007. A more mature and well-supported Python interface to the GPU is [PyCUDA](http://mathema.tician.de/software/pycuda).

If you are familiar with C++, I would also recommend [Thrust](http://thrust.googlecode.com) as a well-supported, mature high-level interface to GPU programming.  The Thrust [Quick Start Guide](http://code.google.com/p/thrust/wiki/QuickStartGuide) is a great place to start.